# If $u$ is a distribution on the interval $(0, 1)$ such that $u' \in L^2 (I)$, then $u \in L^2 (I)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $I$ be the interval $(0, 1)$ and $u$ a distribution on $I$. I would like to prove a lemma used in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4811168/368425) answer, i.e.,

> If $u' \in L^2 (I)$ then $u \in L^2 (I)$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

We fix some $\psi \in C^\infty_c (I)$ such that $\int_I \psi = 1$. For $\varphi \in C^\infty_c (I)$, we denote by $T_\varphi$ the anti-derivative of $\varphi - (\int_I \varphi) \psi$. Then $T_\varphi \in C^\infty_c (I)$ with $(T_\varphi)' = \varphi - (\int_I \varphi) \psi$ and $\|T_\varphi \|_{L^2} \le (1 + \| \psi \|_{L^2}) \| \varphi \|_{L^2}$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle u, \varphi \rangle &= \left \langle u, (T_\varphi)' + \left ( \int_I \varphi \right) \psi \right \rangle \\
&= - \left \langle u', T_\varphi  \right \rangle + \left ( \int_I \varphi \right) \langle u, \psi \rangle,
\end{align*}
$$

which implies
$$
\begin{align*}
|\langle u, \varphi \rangle| &\le  \|u' \|_{L^2} \| T_\varphi \|_{L^2} + \| \varphi \|_{L^2} |\langle u, \psi \rangle| \\
&\le [\|u' \|_{L^2}(1 + \| \psi \|_{L^2})+|\langle u, \psi \rangle|] \| \varphi \|_{L^2},
\end{align*}
$$

which implies $u$ is indeed a continuous linear functional on $C^\infty_c (I)$. Notice that $C^\infty_c (I)$ is dense in $L^2 (I)$. The claim then follows from Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: Seems correct to me. Notice that your Lemma also follows from Sobolev's inequalities and the fact that the domain is bounded since $\dot H^1 \subset C^\alpha \subset L^\infty \subset L^2$. It also follows from the Poincaré-Wirtinger inequalities.

Comment: @LL3.14 Thank you so much for your verification!

Comment: However I think you should detail how you got the $\|T_\varphi\|_{L^2}$ bound (since this is almost your claim)

Comment: @LL3.14 You are right! I upper-bounded $\|T_\varphi\|_{L^2}$ but mis-read it as $\|(T_\varphi)'\|_{L^2}$. Ah this is where we have to use Poincaré’s inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LL3.14 remarked in a comment. This gist of the proof is the inequality $\|T_\varphi \|_{L^2} \le (1 + \| \psi \|_{L^2}) \| \varphi \|_{L^2}$ at which we use the Poincaré’s inequality, i.e.,

> **Brezis' Proposition 8.13 (Poincaré's inequality)**. Suppose $I$ is a **bounded** open interval of $\mathbb R$. Then there exists a constant $C$ (depending on $|I|<\infty$ ) such that
> $$
> \|u\|_{W^{1, p}(I)} \leq C\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^p(I)} \quad \forall u \in W_0^{1, p}(I)
> $$
> In other words, on $W_0^{1, p}$, the quantity $\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^p(I)}$ is a norm equivalent to the $W^{1, p}$ norm.