# Brezis' exercise 8.17: the domain of $A^*$ where $A u=u''-xu'$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces, adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.17** Let $H=L^2(I)$ and $A: D(A) \subset H \rightarrow H$ be the unbounded operator defined by $A u=u''-xu'$, whose domain $D(A)$ will be made precise below. Determine $A^{*}, D\left(A^{*}\right), N(A)$, and $N\left(A^{*}\right)$ in the following cases:
>
> 1. $D(A)=\left\{u \in H^2 (I) : u(0)=u(1)=0\right\}$.
> 2. $D(A)=H^2(I)$.
> 3. $D(A)=\left\{u \in H^2(I) : u(0)=u(1)=u'(0)=u'(1)=0\right\}$.
> 4. $D(A)=\left\{u \in H^2(I) : u(0)=u(1)\right\}$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt. Could you please have a check on my computation of $D(A^*)$?

---

Let $A^* : D(A^*) \subset H \to H$ be the adjoint of $A$. We have the duality
$$
\int_I v (Au) = \int_I (A^*v)u,
\quad v \in D(A^*), u \in D(A),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\int_I v (u''-xu') = \int_I (A^*v)u,
\quad v \in D(A^*), u \in D(A).
\qquad (*)
$$

We have $(*)$ [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4811168/368425) $D(A^*) \subset H^2 (I)$. By integration by parts, $(*)$ is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I (A^*v)u &= \int_I (v''+xv'+v)u \\
&\quad + (vu'-v'u) (1) - (vu'-v'u) (0) + (vu) (1), \\
&\quad  \forall  v \in D(A^*), u \in D(A).
\end{align*}
\qquad (**)
$$

It follows from $(**)$ and $C^\infty_c (I) \subset D(A)$ that $A^*v = v''+xv'+v$ and
$$
D(A^*) = \{ v \in H^2 (I) : (vu'-v'u) (1) - (vu'-v'u) (0) + (vu) (1) = 0
\quad \forall u \in D(A) \}.
\quad (***)
$$

1. We have $(***)$ implies
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   D(A^*) &= \{ v \in H^2 (I) : (vu') (1) - (vu') (0) = 0 \quad \forall u \in D(A) \} \\
   &= \{ v \in H^2 (I) : v(1) = v(0) = 0 \}.
   \end{align*}
   $$
2. We have $(***)$ implies
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   D(A^*) &= \{ v \in H^2 (I) : (vu'-v'u) (1) - (vu'-v'u) (0) + (vu) (1) = 0 \quad \forall u \in H^2 (I) \} \\
   &= \{ v \in H^2 (I) : v(1) = v(0) = v'(1) = v'(0) = 0 \}.
   \end{align*}
   $$
3. Clearly, $D(A^*) = H^2 (I)$.
4. We have $(***)$ implies
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   D(A^*) &= \{ v \in H^2 (I) : (vu')(1) - (vu')(0) -[v'(1) - v'(0)-v(1)]u(0) = 0 \quad \forall u \in D(A) \} \\
   &= \{ v \in H^2 (I) : v(1) = v(0) = v'(1) - v'(0) = 0 \}.
   \end{align*}
   $$